# how can i update a desktop shortcut icon immediatly without flush all the desktop?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

I have created a desktop shortcut and i want to change its icon without refreshing the desktop.

Now, I create new icon file and call the SetIconLocation function .
Result : The shortcut icon is not change immediatly, only after refreshing the desktop by mouse press, the icon has been updated.

if i call the SHChangeNotify - the icon refreshs immediatly but all the desktop is refreshing ... and i dont want the desktop to be refreshed, only the shortcut should.

How can i resolve this issue ?

B.t.y - i works with WIN7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What function in win32 is been called when i press on "change icon" button of the desktop shortcut properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871474/what-function-in-win32-is-been-called-when-i-press-on-change-icon-button-of-th)

Comment: The icon should update automatically when you call IPersistFile::Save. Did you remember to save your changes?

Comment: The IPersistFile::Save actually save the file - but it doesnt show well when i look at the icon, update shell is needed.what is the exact flags i need to sent to SHChangeNotify for this specific item?

Comment: As I noted on another thread (since you submitted this question via multiple support channels), it's SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE and pass the shortcut path as the argument. But IPersistFile::Save should be doing that for you.